# Eclipse does not resolve dependencies

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have declared dependencies in several subproject to another specific subproject like

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation project(':projectx')
  ...
}
```

However all subprojects can not resolve this dependency, however `ctrl+click` works an jumps direcly to the class.

I am confused, but I guess this might be an Eclipse problem. Any idea? Are there any infos from my side are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading from Gradle 7.5.1 to 7.4.2 solved the exact same problem for me. Windows -> Preferences -> Gradle -> Specific Gradle Version